# 'finally' actions for coroutines

Tags: caliburn.micro, coroutine, cancellation

Imagine I have a coroutine which uses the implementation of `Loader` included in the CM docs, and I use it to show a busy indicator on my page

Now imagine the user attempts to add an object which already exists to the data store - naturally during the coroutine the 'save' operation will fail, meaning the coroutine will cancel execution

If this happens, the enumerator never reaches my `Loader.Hide()` call to hide the busy indicator - I'm wondering if there is already a mechanism in place to allow some `IResult` implementations to execute even if the coroutine fails?

Example:

```
    public IEnumerator<IResult> SaveData()
    {
        yield return Framework.Coroutines.Loader.Show("Saving Data");
        yield return new Framework.Coroutines.SaveOperation(SomeObject);
        yield return Framework.Coroutines.Loader.Hide();
    }
```

If the coroutine fails legitimately on the second step, the busy indicator remains on screen, leaving the user no chance to correct their errors and attempt a re-save (and stopping any interaction with the underlying UI!)

I could just extend the implementation of coroutine and have iterators that have a flag which says whether they are allowed to execute when there is an error - just wondering if anyone has done this already or if it's a part of the framework I'm missing?

Comment: Basically you need to implement your own custom [SequentialResult](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a9efed22b615#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/SequentialResult.cs). Then you can customize the corutine creation with `Coroutine.CreateParentEnumerator = (inner) => new MySequentialResult(inner);`

Comment: Thanks for this, I've reimplemented `SequentialResult` and created an interface which subclasses `IResult` which contains a flag to determine whether the routine is allowed to run after a prior failure. The `SequentialResult` still returns the original error. Works well - going to test with a few of my screens to make sure there are no issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Caliburn.Micro [Action Filters](http://marcoamendola.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/a-caliburn-micro-recipe-filters/). See `SetBusyAttribute`.
The declarative style of attributes is transparent and makes the code easier to manage.

Comment: This is nice, I do like the loader implemenation but this provides a less intrusive implementation, though it does mean binding `IsBusy` on the View which I liked about the Loader (you didn't need it and I'm lazy! :))